# Где ошибка в коде дискорд бота на Питоне?

Tags: python, discord, бот

```
@bot.command()
def Stuff (message):
 import random



 imgs = [
     "img_url",
     "img_url"
 ]

 send(random.choice(imgs))
```

При запуске вот такая ошибка:

```
PS D:\Bots> python bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 13, in <module>
    @bot.command()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1262, in decorator
    result = command(*args, **kwargs)(func)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1433, in decorator
    return cls(func, name=name, **attrs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 217, in __init__
    raise TypeError('Callback must be a coroutine.')
TypeError: Callback must be a coroutine.
```

Answer (score 1):

В функцию передается обязательный аргумент, содержащий контекст выполнения команды. Правильнее назвать его не просто `message`, а `context` или `ctx`, как в документации.

У этого контекста и вызывается метод `send()`.

И нет необходимости импортировать библиотеку `random` каждый раз при вызове команды.

Также функция должна быть асинхронной, то есть не просто `def`, а `async def`

```
import random

@bot.command()
async def Stuff(ctx):
    imgs = [
        "img_url",
        "img_url"
    ]

    await ctx.send(random.choice(imgs))
```